# How are many comparings connected? Do I need the brackets for `(x != y) && z`?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to know how many "comparings" in Ruby are connected. Do I need the brackets for the following expression?

`(x != y) && z`

My guess is **no**, but I'm not 100% familiar on how Ruby evaluates such things. I would say: comparing operators (don't know how they are called correctly) like `!=`, `==` etc. are evaluated first, and after this the combination operators like `&&` and `||` are evaluated.

Where do I find more informations about this?

Answer (score 4):

*No* you don't need the parentheses: `!=` has higher precedence than `&&`.

Refer to the [precedence table](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) for more info.

Comment: As a side note: be careful using the control-flow operators `and`, `or` and `not`; they behave differently because they have different precendence than their boolean counterparts! This is especially a problem with assignments because the precedence of the assignment operator is in between the control-flow and boolean operators. `f = false || true #=> f is true` whereas `f = false or true #=> f is false`. With parentheses: `f = (false || true) #=> f is true` whereas `(f = false) or true #=> f is false`. Takeaway message: only use `||`, `&&` and `!` in `if`-clauses, the others for control flow.